# Java Mouse Events not registering on OSX

Tags: java, macos, swing, events

The software I am working with is written in Java.  This particular problem only manifests on Mac, the program functions properly on Windows and Linux.

I basically wrote a custom "tooltip" that follows the mouse around the main window of the application.  It is actually a separate, undecorated frame (we will call the "display frame") that changes location based off of mouseMoved events that are received by the window the cursor is moving over.  The default location is slightly below and to the right of the cursor, but when it reaches edges of the window it can "flip" to the left side or the top side of the cursor.  This works properly on other platforms, as mentioned before, but it appears on the mac that this mouseMoved event is somehow consumed by the display frame, before it ever gets to the main application.  So that window is never receiving mouseMoved events, therefore never moving and following the cursor.  The only time the display frame changes location, is if the cursor enters it.  Then, the main window triggers a mouseExited event, which causes the display frame to setVisible(false) (I don't want to show the display frame if the cursor isn't in the main window).  This then triggers a mouseEntered event, which causes the display frame to be redrawn below and to the right, as it is supposed to be.

I have tried setting the focus to the main window when the redraw method is called, and I have printed out .hasFocus() once this is done, and the other window now has focus, but is still not receiving mouseMoved events.  Also, putting a mouse listener on the display frame does not work because the mouseMoved events I am interested in are not within the actual frame of the displayFrame, so those are never triggered either.

The very strange part, is there is a way to produce the proper behavior on the mac. Having the display frame follow the mouse around is a certain "Tool Mode" that can be selected within the application.  While in this mode the user can also add additional features to the main window.  If the user left clicks while in this mode, a small dialog pops up asking you to name the new feature, if you do so and click "Okay", or don't and click "Cancel", now the display frame will follow the mouse around.  You can break it again if you move too quickly and manage to get the cursor inside the display frame before it can redraw, and then you're back to square one where it won't follow you around.

The dialog box requires a parent to be set when it is shown, and we thought perhaps it was setting the main window as its parent and that somehow when it came and then left, the mouse events were then passed on to the parent.  But, the dialog box is setting its parent to the display frame.  So that is sadly not the case either.

This problem occurs on various versions of osx and on different versions of Java.  For reference I am running 10.9.2, but it has been replicated on 10.9.3, 10.9.4, and 10.8, 10.6.
I am running Java 1.7.0_51 and 1.7.0_67.

I have spent some time looking online and haven't come up with anything that has really helped and would appreciate any help from here.  Below is a much simpler sample program that I wrote that replicates the problem I am experiencing.

Thanks.
package mouseMovedProblem;

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputListener;

public class MainFrame extends JPanel{
    public static MainFrame mainFrame;

    MainFrame(){
//      setOpaque(false);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        MouseListener ml = new MouseListener();
        addMouseListener(ml);
        addMouseMotionListener(ml);
    }

    private class MouseListener implements MouseInputListener{
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
//          System.out.println("Mouse clicked");
            DisplayFrame.showDisplay(e.getX(), e.getY());
            String test = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(DisplayFrame.getInstance(), 
                    "This is a test","test");
        }
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
//          DisplayFrame.showDisplay(e.getX(), e.getY());
        }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
//          DisplayFrame.showDisplay(e.getX(), e.getY());
        }
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
//          DisplayFrame.showDisplay(e.getX(), e.getY());
        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            DisplayFrame.getInstance().setVisible(false);
        }
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
//          System.out.println("Mouse moved");
            DisplayFrame.showDisplay(e.getX(), e.getY());
        }
    }

    public static MainFrame getInstance(){
        if(mainFrame == null){
            mainFrame = new MainFrame();
        }
        Dimension size = new Dimension(900,700);
        mainFrame.setPreferredSize(size);
        mainFrame.setMinimumSize(size);

        return mainFrame;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(getInstance(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}

class DisplayFrame extends JFrame{
    public static DisplayFrame display;

    DisplayFrame(){
        setUndecorated(true);
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        JTabbedPane tPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tPane.setTabPlacement(JTabbedPane.BOTTOM);
        tPane.addTab("Black", panel1);
        tPane.addTab("White", panel2);
        add(tPane);
    }

    public static DisplayFrame getInstance(){
        if(display == null){
            display = new DisplayFrame();
        }

        // Set size
        Dimension size = new Dimension(200,200);
        display.setPreferredSize(size);
        display.setMinimumSize(size);
        display.setMaximumSize(size);

        return display;
    }

    public static void showDisplay(int x, int y){
        getInstance();

        int compX = (int) MainFrame.getInstance().getLocationOnScreen().getX();
        int compY = (int) MainFrame.getInstance().getLocationOnScreen().getY();
    // Should be the location 10 pixels to the right and 20 pixels below the cursor             
        int newX = compX+x+10;
        int newY = compY+y+20;

    // Set location
        display.setLocation(newX, newY);

        if(!display.isVisible()){
            display.setVisible(true);
        }
    // This is to make sure the frame doesn't get hidden behind the main window     
        display.toFront(); 

    } // end method 
}
```

Comment: Beware, anything higher in the container hirarcy with a MouseListener or MouseMotitionListener registered will block mouse events to components lower then it. Don't know if this is the problem, but it will be a concern in larger applications ;)

Comment: Make sure you are creating your UI from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details

Comment: I had no issues (one I got your example into a runnable state).  Make sure there are no other components within the UI above the `MainFrame` (which I assume is a `JPanel`) that have any mouse listeners...

Comment: Beware, you `getInstance` implementation is prone to thread race conditions, that is, with two threads running, it's possible to create two instance of the object.  You should consider using `synchronisation`, `Lock` or `enum` instead...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once I corrected your code so it would compile and run, I had no issues with your example...

MacOS X 10.9.4, Java 1.8.0_05.

If there are any other components on the screen which have a registered `MouseListener` or `MouseMoitionListener`, they will block events going through to parent components.  There is a trick you can use to overcome this is issue, it's a little bit more work, but it does work.

Basically, you can register an `AWTListener` with the `Toolkit` masked to deliver `MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK` events.  This are global, so you will receive ALL mouse motion events that go through the Event Queue, so you will need filter them appropriately, for example...

```
import java.awt.AWTEvent;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.AWTEventListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class MainFrame extends JPanel {

    MainFrame() {
//      setOpaque(false);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        MouseListener ml = new MouseListener();
        addMouseListener(ml);
        addMouseMotionListener(ml);

        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
                MouseEvent evt = (MouseEvent) event;
                Point p = evt.getPoint();
                if (evt.getSource() != MainFrame.this) {
                    p = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(evt.getComponent(), p, MainFrame.this);
                }
                if (MainFrame.this.getBounds().contains(p)) {
                    System.out.println(p.x + "x" + p.y);
                }
            }
        }, AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK);
    }

    private class MouseListener extends MouseAdapter {

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
//          System.out.println("Mouse clicked");
            DisplayFrame.showDisplay(e.getX(), e.getY());
        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
//          DisplayFrame.showDisplay(e.getX(), e.getY());
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
//          DisplayFrame.showDisplay(e.getX(), e.getY());
        }

        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
//          DisplayFrame.showDisplay(e.getX(), e.getY());
        }

        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            DisplayFrame.getInstance().setVisible(false);
        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Mouse moved " + e.getX() + "x" + e.getY());
            DisplayFrame.showDisplay(e.getX(), e.getY());
        }
    }

    private static MainFrame mainFrame;

    public static MainFrame getInstance() {
        if (mainFrame == null) {
            mainFrame = new MainFrame();
            mainFrame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            JPanel blocker = new JPanel();
            blocker.setBackground(Color.RED);
            blocker.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
            MouseAdapter ma = new MouseAdapter() {
            };
            blocker.addMouseListener(ma);
            blocker.addMouseMotionListener(ma);
            mainFrame.add(blocker);

            Dimension size = new Dimension(900, 700);
            mainFrame.setPreferredSize(size);
            mainFrame.setMinimumSize(size);
        }

        return mainFrame;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(getInstance(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame.pack();

                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    static class DisplayFrame extends JFrame {

        public static DisplayFrame display;

        DisplayFrame() {
            setUndecorated(true);
            JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
            panel1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
            panel2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            JTabbedPane tPane = new JTabbedPane();
            tPane.setTabPlacement(JTabbedPane.BOTTOM);
            tPane.addTab("Black", panel1);
            tPane.addTab("White", panel2);
            add(tPane);
        }

        public static DisplayFrame getInstance() {
            if (display == null) {
                display = new DisplayFrame();
            }

            // Set size
            Dimension size = new Dimension(200, 200);
            display.setPreferredSize(size);
            display.setMinimumSize(size);
            display.setMaximumSize(size);

            return display;
        }

        public static void showDisplay(int x, int y) {
            getInstance();

            int compX = (int) MainFrame.getInstance().getLocationOnScreen().getX();
            int compY = (int) MainFrame.getInstance().getLocationOnScreen().getY();
            // Should be the location 10 pixels to the right and 20 pixels below the cursor             
            int newX = compX + x + 10;
            int newY = compY + y + 20;

            // Set location
            display.setLocation(newX, newY);

            if (!display.isVisible()) {
                display.setVisible(true);
            }
            // This is to make sure the frame doesn't get hidden behind the main window     
            display.toFront();

        } // end method 
    }
}
```

This example will print the x/y position of the mouse.  You will see that when your `MouseMoitionListener` stops receiving events, the `AWTListener` containers to print out results.

### Updated

I was able to test it using Java 1.7.0_15 and was able to replicate the issue.  This seems to be a bug in the Java 7, as even the `AWTListener` stopped displaying output...

So what's the solution?  Upgrade to Java 8...

Okay, if you can't do that, you can use a "hack" work around...basically, you start `Thread` or `javax.swing.Timer` which probes `java.awt.MouseInfo` for the `java.awt.PointerInfo` and make determinations about the location of the cursor on the screen, for example...

```
Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        PointerInfo pi = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
        Point p = pi.getLocation();
        SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(p, MainFrame.this);
        if (MainFrame.this.getBounds().contains(p)) {
            System.out.println("pi = " + p.x + "x" + p.y);
        }
    }
});
timer.start();
```

The important thing about this to:

1. Make sure the mouse pointer is within the confines of your component and
2. Make sure it has changed before you update anything

As an example...

```
import java.awt.AWTEvent;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.PointerInfo;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.AWTEventListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class MainFrame extends JPanel {

    MainFrame() {
//      setOpaque(false);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        MouseListener ml = new MouseListener();
        addMouseListener(ml);
        addMouseMotionListener(ml);

        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
                MouseEvent evt = (MouseEvent) event;
                Point p = evt.getPoint();
                if (evt.getSource() != MainFrame.this) {
                    p = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(evt.getComponent(), p, MainFrame.this);
                }
                if (MainFrame.this.getBounds().contains(p)) {
                    System.out.println(p.x + "x" + p.y);
                }
            }
        }, AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK);

        Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                PointerInfo pi = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
                Point p = pi.getLocation();
                SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(p, MainFrame.this);
                if (MainFrame.this.getBounds().contains(p)) {
                    System.out.println("pi = " + p.x + "x" + p.y);
                }
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    private class MouseListener extends MouseAdapter {

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
//          System.out.println("Mouse clicked");
            DisplayFrame.showDisplay(e.getX(), e.getY());
        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
//          DisplayFrame.showDisplay(e.getX(), e.getY());
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
//          DisplayFrame.showDisplay(e.getX(), e.getY());
        }

        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
//          DisplayFrame.showDisplay(e.getX(), e.getY());
        }

        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            DisplayFrame.getInstance().setVisible(false);
        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Mouse moved " + e.getX() + "x" + e.getY());
            DisplayFrame.showDisplay(e.getX(), e.getY());
        }
    }

    private static MainFrame mainFrame;

    public static MainFrame getInstance() {
        if (mainFrame == null) {
            mainFrame = new MainFrame();
            mainFrame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            JPanel blocker = new JPanel();
            blocker.setBackground(Color.RED);
            blocker.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
            MouseAdapter ma = new MouseAdapter() {
            };
            blocker.addMouseListener(ma);
            blocker.addMouseMotionListener(ma);
            mainFrame.add(blocker);

            Dimension size = new Dimension(900, 700);
            mainFrame.setPreferredSize(size);
            mainFrame.setMinimumSize(size);
        }

        return mainFrame;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(getInstance(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame.pack();

                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    static class DisplayFrame extends JFrame {

        public static DisplayFrame display;

        DisplayFrame() {
            setUndecorated(true);
            JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
            panel1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
            panel2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            JTabbedPane tPane = new JTabbedPane();
            tPane.setTabPlacement(JTabbedPane.BOTTOM);
            tPane.addTab("Black", panel1);
            tPane.addTab("White", panel2);
            add(tPane);
        }

        public static DisplayFrame getInstance() {
            if (display == null) {
                display = new DisplayFrame();
            }

            // Set size
            Dimension size = new Dimension(200, 200);
            display.setPreferredSize(size);
            display.setMinimumSize(size);
            display.setMaximumSize(size);

            return display;
        }

        public static void showDisplay(int x, int y) {
            getInstance();

            int compX = (int) MainFrame.getInstance().getLocationOnScreen().getX();
            int compY = (int) MainFrame.getInstance().getLocationOnScreen().getY();
            // Should be the location 10 pixels to the right and 20 pixels below the cursor             
            int newX = compX + x + 10;
            int newY = compY + y + 20;

            // Set location
            display.setLocation(newX, newY);

            if (!display.isVisible()) {
                display.setVisible(true);
            }
            // This is to make sure the frame doesn't get hidden behind the main window     
            display.toFront();

        } // end method 
    }
}
```

Comment: Confirmed with java 1.7.0_55 on Mac OS X 10.9.4.

Comment: This fix seems to break when the window is moved or resized. The bounds don't update, so events keep firing in the window's original position instead of its new one.

Comment: Given the fact that you ask the frame for its bounds each time an event occurs, I can't see how that's possible...

Comment: I don't understand it either, but that's what's happening. I've added `System.out.println(MainFrame.this.getBounds());` to the start of each timer tick to confirm, and it prints the same bounds even while/after moving or resizing.